# Where does g++ (with -fno-implicit-templates) get template definitons from, if I dont explicitly instantiatie them?

Tags: c++, templates, g++

The following code works.

```
/* hello.cc */

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void vec_print()
{
    std::vector<int> is(10, 1);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < is.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << is[i] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

/* main.cc */

void vec_print();

int main()
{
    vec_print();
}
```

When i complie this with

```
g++ -fno-implicit-templates -Wall -Wextra -c hello.cc
g++ -fno-implicit-templates -Wall -Wextra -c main.cc
g++ hello.o main.o -o hello
```

I get no warnings and it compiles and runs fine. I am under the impression this shouldn't happen. I am using gcc 4.4.5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That option doesn't prevent all template instantiations, just non-inline ones:

> -fno-implicit-templates
>   Never emit code for non-inline templates which are instantiated implicitly (i.e. by use); only emit code for explicit instantiations. See Template Instantiation, for more information.

The compiler inlines all the `vector` member functions used in your code, so compilation succeeds.

The following will fail when compiled with that option, since it requires a non-inline instantiation:

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    auto f = &std::vector<int>::resize;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the manpage:

```
   -fno-implicit-templates
       Never emit code for non-inline templates which are instantiated implicitly (i.e. by use); only emit code for explicit instantiations.
```

Now in your example you are instantiating the type, and then calling methods that are *defined* inside the class template definition and are thus implicitly `inline`.

You can try this:

```
template <typename T>
void noop( T const & ) {}
int main() {
   noop(1);
}
```

And then compile with g++ -fno-implicit-templates -o test test.cpp